# Serial Communation(RS232) Software for SR830 Labiew

Tags: serial-port, labview

The driver Software provided in NI webpage for SR830 is for GPIB.I am looking for a driver Software for RS232 communication.

Can someone please share it here!!!

Answer (score 0):

NI provides RS-232 I/O through [NI-VISA](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-visa-14.0.1/5023/en/), and NI has a detailed how-to called [Connecting Instruments via Serial](http://www.ni.com/getting-started/set-up-hardware/instrument-control/serial-connect) which can guide you.

If you have the GPIB instrument driver, you can convert it to RS-232 by replacing the NI-488.2 VIs with the equivalent NI-VISA VIs.